# Accessing Trino Via Python

Tags: python, sql, database, trino, query-engine

I'm trying to access trino via python and I keep getting the error below. This is to access the trino interface and retrieve data from oracle. Please advise on how this can be resolved.

````
HttpError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_166/2315044439.py in <module>
     10 )
     11 cur = conn.cursor()
---> 12 cur.execute('SELECT * FROM system.runtime.nodes')
     13 rows = cur.fetchall()
     14 print(cur)

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/dbapi.py in execute(self, operation, params)
    394         else:
    395             self._query = trino.client.TrinoQuery(self._request, sql=operation)
--> 396             result = self._query.execute()
    397         self._iterator = iter(result)
    398         return result

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/client.py in execute(self, additional_http_headers)
    505 
    506         response = self._request.post(self._sql, additional_http_headers)
--> 507         status = self._request.process(response)
    508         self.query_id = status.id
    509         self._stats.update({"queryId": self.query_id})

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/client.py in process(self, http_response)
    382     def process(self, http_response) -> TrinoStatus:
    383         if not http_response.ok:
--> 384             self.raise_response_error(http_response)
    385 
    386         http_response.encoding = "utf-8"

~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/trino/client.py in raise_response_error(self, http_response)
    373             raise exceptions.Http503Error("error 503: service unavailable")
    374 
--> 375         raise exceptions.HttpError(
    376             "error {}{}".format(
    377                 http_response.status_code,

HttpError: error 401: b'Unknown signing key ID'  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

The http 401 error suggests you have some kind of authentication problem and since we can't see the conn object construction in your code above (likely to hide your creds from us ;) then I'd suggest that's all it was.  Similar situation identified in https://github.com/trinodb/trino/issues/9796.  I ran your code above post my conn object creation and it looks perfectly correct to me (and ran successfully).